# Cannot get iNotes Calendar Data in Xpages

Tags: xpages

I cannot get the iNotesCalendar control to work.

It works in a tearoom.nsf. But if I put the controls in normal mail.nsf I always get a blank calendar.

I can get JSON via a web browser. Looks like this:

[image]

My code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:restService
        id="restService1"
        pathInfo="/inoteslegacyjson"
        preventDojoStore="false">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:calendarJsonLegacyService
                viewName="calendarOutline"
                var="entry"
                contentType="text/plain"
                colCalendarDate="CalDateTime"
                colStartTime="StartDateTime"
                colEndTime="EndDateTime"
                colSubject="For"
                colChair="Chair">
            </xe:calendarJsonLegacyService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:calendarView
        id="calendarView1"
        jsId="cview1"
        type="#{javascript:sessionScope.dateRangeActions_selectedValue}"
        storeComponentId="restService1"
        style="width:100%">
        <xe:this.summarize>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:summarize = sessionScope.calendarFormatActions_selectedValue == "true";}]]>
        </xe:this.summarize>
    </xe:calendarView>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to present the calendar view as iNotesCalendar for a normal mail database which is based on mail.ntf.

Your question's example is designed for and works with the teamroom.nsf. It uses a specialized view "calendarOutline". All calendarJsonLegacyService's properties which start with "col" define the specific column names of this view. So, you can't really use this example to read a "normal" calendar view of a mail database.

Luckily, all `calendarJsonLegacyService` properties' **default values** are dedicated to the "normal" calendar view "**($Calendar)** | **Calendar**" of mail boxes.

Change your code this way:

- delete all "col..." parameters
- change `viewName` property to "Calendar"
- add property `databaseName` with value "yourServerName!!pathToMailDatabase.nsf"

Your restService would look like this then:

```xml
  <xe:restService
      id="restService1"
      pathInfo="/inoteslegacyjson"
      preventDojoStore="false">
      <xe:this.service>
         <xe:calendarJsonLegacyService
            viewName="Calendar"
            contentType="text/plain"
            databaseName="Server1!!mail.nsf">
         </xe:calendarJsonLegacyService>
      </xe:this.service>
   </xe:restService>
```

Comment: Knut, this works absolutely perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for xe:restService and xe:calendarView looks similar to what I use.

I have experienced issues with using xe:calendarView with Internet Explorer 11. The problem is that the calendar is empty - exactly as what you experience. In order for it to work with IE11 I force IE11 to act as IE10 by setting the X-UA-Compatible to "IE=10".

Comment: Per, I am not using IE. I have tried this in XPiNC and on Safari. It is very strange. Is there something else that has to be done? I am able to see calendar entries in the tearoom.